# FFMpeg compilation error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg, x86-64

I am trying to compile ffmpeg (0.9.0.git) with x264(0.120) like this

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame \
   --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-libx264 \
   --enable-pthreads --disable-doc --enable-avfilter \
   --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-ffprobe
make
```

and I encounter the following error:

```
LD  ffmpeg_g
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_MM_FIX_0_707106781", referenced from:
      _filter in libavfilter.a(vf_fspp.o)
  "_MM_FIX_0_541196100", referenced from:
      _filter in libavfilter.a(vf_fspp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

Any idea what the fix might be?

**Update:** Might be unrelated but this discussion https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30093 says the issue was ffmpeg picking up llvm instead of gcc-4.2 but then this had already fixed in 0.7.4

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.mail-archive.com/ffmpeg-trac@avcodec.org/msg00778.html) suggests adding `--cc=clang` to the configure command which fixed the issue